# Facing some weird issue on react-native app with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm getting the below issue suddenly after reinstalling my packages, the app is working fine but it's giving me the following typescript error, I found that my redux version changed from 4.0.4 to 4.0.5 which I reverted back but still getting error

```
Argument of type 'StoreEnhancer<{ dispatch: {}; }, {}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StoreEnhancer<{}, {}>'.
  Types of parameters 'next' and 'next' are incompatible.
    Types of parameters 'preloadedState' and 'preloadedState' are incompatible.
      Type 'DeepPartial<S> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'PreloadedState<S> | undefined'.
        Type 'DeepPartial<S>' is not assignable to type 'PreloadedState<S>'.
```

```
   composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware, reduxLogger))
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed react-native-elements from my application and didn't get the error again, not sure but it seems the library has lots of issue, it's not a stable one.